# PHP: display data retrieved from database (Silverstripe CMS)

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a problem using Silverstripe CMS.
I have basic SQL query of which results I would like to display in `<ul><li>` menu. It should be really easy but I failed while browsing documentation. I found some more complex examples (Project, Students), but it seems to me that should exists some easier way to do this. Can anyone help or please give me a hint?

To sum up: I would like to run a db sql query and display data as list.

My **WishPage.php**

```
class WishPage extends Page {
    // some code which is irrelevant for this matter, but works fine
}

class WishPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array('AddNewWishForm');

    public function AddNewWishForm() {
        // here you can add data to db
    }

    // Now I would like to show it; and here is the problem.
    public function ShowWishList() {
    $records = DB::query ("SELECT Title FROM Wishes;");
    return $records;
    }

}
```

My template **WishPage.ss**

```
<% include SideBar %>
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">

<div id="WishForm">
    <h2>Try it</h2>
    $AddNewWishForm
</div>

</div>
```

Update
My **Wishes.php**

```
<?php
class Wishes extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Name' => 'Text',
        'Comment' => 'Text'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the SS built-in functionality to fetch the entries from the DB:

```
// returns the list of all wishes
public function ShowWishList() {
    return Wishes::get();
}
```

and in the frontend you can just:

```
<ul>
<% loop $ShowWishList %><li>$Name: $Comment</li><% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

This requires that you have a list of DataObjects of course.

Comment: Thank you for the update! Should `return Wishes::get();` match to the table name (it's called Whish)? If so, I get server error after updating function `ShowWishList` this way.

Comment: Yes, the "Wishes" comes from the name of the DataObject - which is the same as the table name. You can find further information about how to create a DataObject and its table here: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/datamodel How does your DataObject look like?

Comment: I've uptaded my question with information about Wishes.php. If I use `return Wishes::get();` in **WishPage.php** > `function ShowWishList()` "Server error" is shown instead of expected output.

Comment: You can put the site in dev mode by adding Director::set_environment_type('dev'); to mysite/_config.php  This will tell you what the error actually is. It sounds like you have created a DataObject called Whish, then ran a dev/build and then have changed it to Wish. Perhaps run another dev/build which should create the Wish database table.

Answer (score 1):

Decision of spekulatius should work well.

If you wont try with [SQLQuery](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/sqlquery)

```
public function getWishes(){
    $query = new SQLQuery();
    $query->setFrom('Wishes')->setSelect('"Name", "Comment"');
    //$query->addWhere('');
    $result = $query->execute();
    //Debug::show($result);
    $list = ArrayList::create();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $list->push($row);
    }
    return $list;
}
```

in theme

```
<ul>
    <% loop $getWishes %><li>$Name: $Comment</li><% end_loop %>
</ul>
```